# Is the function of nanosleep() removed in C++14?

Tags: c++, c++14

I tried to compile the below code calling `nanosleep()` using C++14, but it failed with an error:

```
'nanosleep' was not declared in this scope
     nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
```

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct timespec ts;
    int i;
    ts.tv_sec = 3;
    ts.tv_nsec = 0;
    printf("nanosleep start.¥n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        int x;
        x += i;
    }
    nanosleep(&ts, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `-DNDEBUG -O3 -DNDEBUG -o -c nanosleep-test.cpp -std=c++14 -fPIC -Wall -Wpedantic -Werror`. Removing `-std=c++14`, I got it compiled. So is it correct to say that C++14 removes `nanosleep()`?

Comment: `nanosleep` is not a C++ standard function. It's an POSIX function.

Comment: Use [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead

Comment: Shouldn't that rather be [std::thread::sleep_for()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)?

Comment: also [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/5K3dMc)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nanosleep` is a POSIX function and has nothing to do with the C++ standard.

What you want for C++ is `sleep_for` found in the `thread` and `chrono` header.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 3):

> is it correct to say that c++14 removes nanosleep()?

No, it is not correct. Function `nanosleep` has never been in C++.

There is `nanosleep` function in the POSIX C standard. Unless you aren compiling for a POSIX system, it is not reasonable to expect it to be declared.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do compile for a POSIX system. Is there a way to make it compile? Should I add "#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE ****" before #include <time.h>?

Comment: @issac Yes, with GCC you'll need to either define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `199309L` or greater, or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to any value before including any header. This is simplest by defining the macro in the compile command. Even simpler is to use `-std=gnu++14` which enables POSIX extensions as well as GNU extensions. Or you could use the C++ standard function as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: @eerorika, thank you very much. Adding -std=gnu++14 solved it. Thanks!